# Layout issue fixes when viewport height is decreased

Tags: html, css, viewport

On the following page
http://portabellointeriors.com/blog/

Some items overlap, yet when you decrease the height of the viewport and return it to the original size, the layout fixes itself.

Is there a way in which I can make the layout render correctly before decreasing the viewport size?

Comment: The issue also fixes on refresh. Did you clear your floats?

Comment: Please provide a little more info. And a link to a site, will not help future visitors with the same problem, once the problem has been fixed. 
However it probably has something to do with the javaScript being triggered on resize but not on init

Comment: Which items are overlapping

Comment: divs with the class "post-content" overlap the div underneath with the same class